# Best place for a post-save hook with nested objects

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm building an application that manages dates, in particular recurrence of events. I'm using Django-Rest-Framework for api.
The model consists of a ruleset, and 0 or more rules attached to a ruleset:

```
class RecurrenceRuleset(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, name='id', db_column='id')
    summary = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True, default="")
    rdates = models.TextField(blank=True, default="")
    exdates = models.TextField(blank=True, default="")
    calculated_mindate = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    calculated_maxdate = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

class RecurrenceRule(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, name='id', db_column='id')
    ruleset = models.ForeignKey(RecurrenceRuleset, blank=True, null=True, db_column='parent_ruleset_id', related_name='recurrence_rules')
    summary = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True, default="")
    type = models.CharField(max_length=20)  # RRULE, EXRULE
    frequency = models.CharField(max_length=20)  # YEARLY, MONTHLY etc
    # ... A lot of other model params
```

As I will frequently need to request events in a certain date range, I don't want to recalculate at each GET message if a particular ruleset has dates in the given date range.

As an easy optimization, I will store a 'calculated_mindate / maxdate' fields in the ruleset and only query the rulesets that fits to my query date range. Of course, I will still need to do the calculation to check the exact occurrences, but it will be a much shorter list that the whole table. However, that means I need to update the 'calculated' fields at each post / put / patch of the object.

I will only expose the ruleset object with nested rules. I'm wondering where is the best place to put the calculus of those fields. I see two candidates:
- override post_save in my views
- override restore_object in the serializer

I'm leaning towards restore_object solution as this will also stands if the RecurrenceRuleset object can itself be nested in another one. However, this makes me use the instance._related_data.

Any thoughts on this ?

Comment: have you looked at template loader http://www.jongales.com/blog/2012/02/16/make-django-keep-templates-in-memory/

Comment: Hello, how this is related to my question ?

Comment: You wanted to store this because of frequent use.  So If you stored this in cache you could reuse it anywhere without recalculating variables. There could be other ways you could create persistence.  If that is the problem.  I hope I didn't mis-read your question.

Comment: I'm using Django-rest-framework - I'm building an API actually. And yep, the problem is rather not related to the link you've posted. But thanks anyway